# Java Telnet Applet with jsch1.4.8 cannot input

Tags: java, ssh, telnet, jsch, terminal-emulator

My application was using jsch 1.28 version previously and I was also
using JTA 2.0 for Telnet/SSH terminal everything was working fine until I
moved to the latest version of jsch 1.48, the problem I'm facing is that
I am able to open the SSH Terminal and connect as well but when I try to
execute some command from Keyboard on the Connection terminal it is not
all responding to keystrokes.

I moved to jsch 1.48 because with jsch 1.28 after trying connect via ssh i got error: "Algorithm negotiation fault"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works

I had to add: out_.flush(); after out_ = channel_.getOutputStream(); in the JTAJSch.java plugin file

Answer (score 0):

I have  tried the Shell.java example given in the link  http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html. It works properly with the jsch 1.48.
Could you try it seperatelly from your project to find out the route cause.